# As Far From Land as Possible - DP Solution

Tags: python, dynamic-programming

I was working on a problem from Leetcode "As Far from Land as Possible", which can be found here: https://leetcode.com/problems/as-far-from-land-as-possible/

One solution that is guaranteed to work is to have 4 DP arrays, each of which start from different corners of the grid, and compute the distance to the nearest lands as you head to the opposite corner. In the end, taking the minimum of the elements in all 4 arrays should output the correct solution.

I tried writing a DP solution which would only try to do this one array, computing each by going through the four directions.

My code gives incorrect answers and I can't seem to find where the mistake is.

```py
def maxDistance(self, grid: List[List[int]]) -> int:
        N = len(grid)
        dpfin = [[float('inf') for k in range(N)] for m in range(N)]

        for k in range(N):
            for m in range(N):
                origk = k
                if grid[k][m] == 1:
                    dpfin[k][m] = 0                    
                elif k == 0 and m == 0:
                    pass
                elif k == 0:
                    dpfin[k][m] = min(dpfin[k][m], dpfin[k][m-1] + 1)
                    k = N - 1 - k
                    dpfin[k][m] = min(dpfin[k][m], dpfin[k][m-1] + 1)
                    m = N - 1 - m
                    dpfin[k][m] = min(dpfin[k][m], dpfin[k][m-1] + 1)
                    k = origk
                    dpfin[k][m] = min(dpfin[k][m], dpfin[k][m-1] + 1)
                elif m == 0:
                    dpfin[k][m] = min(dpfin[k][m], dpfin[k-1][m] + 1)
                    k = N - 1 - k
                    dpfin[k][m] = min(dpfin[k][m], dpfin[k-1][m] + 1)
                    m = N - 1 - m
                    dpfin[k][m] = min(dpfin[k][m], dpfin[k-1][m] + 1)
                    k = origk
                    dpfin[k][m] = min(dpfin[k][m], dpfin[k-1][m] + 1)
                else:
                    dpfin[k][m] = min( min(dpfin[k-1][m],dpfin[k][m-1])+1,dpfin[k][m])
                    k = N - 1 - k
                    dpfin[k][m] = min( min(dpfin[k-1][m],dpfin[k][m-1])+1,dpfin[k][m])
                    m = N - 1 - m
                    dpfin[k][m] = min( min(dpfin[k-1][m],dpfin[k][m-1])+1,dpfin[k][m])
                    k = origk
                    dpfin[k][m] = min( min(dpfin[k-1][m],dpfin[k][m-1])+1,dpfin[k][m])

        maxi = 0
        for k in range(N):
            for m in range(N):
                maxi = max(maxi,dpfin[k][m])
        if maxi == float('inf') or maxi == 0:
            return -1
        return maxi
```

Comment: You don't want to solve this using dynamic programming. You should use variation of [BFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search), where you have multiple starting vertices (in this case all land vertices).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to admit that it was pretty hard, but I think I have a first "unoptimized" solution. First the code, then the explanation:

```
class Solution:
    def _rec_fixDP(self, grid, DP, r, c, max_offset, dist):
        if r < 0 or c < 0 or r > max_offset or c > max_offset:
            return

        if grid[r][c] != 1 and (DP[r][c] == -1 or DP[r][c] > dist):
            DP[r][c] = dist
            self._rec_fixDP(grid, DP, r - 1, c, max_offset, dist + 1)
            self._rec_fixDP(grid, DP, r, c - 1, max_offset, dist + 1)
            self._rec_fixDP(grid, DP, r + 1, c, max_offset, dist + 1)
            self._rec_fixDP(grid, DP, r, c + 1, max_offset, dist + 1)

    def _dp_iteration(self, r, c, grid, DP):
        if grid[r][c] == 0:
            dp_left = -1 if r - 1 < 0 else DP[r - 1][c]
            dp_up = -1 if c - 1 < 0 else DP[r][c - 1]

            if dp_left == -1 and dp_up == -1:
                DP[r][c] = -1
            elif dp_left == -1 and dp_up != -1:
                DP[r][c] = dp_up + 1
            elif dp_left != -1 and dp_up == -1:
                DP[r][c] = dp_left + 1
            else:
                DP[r][c] = min(dp_left, dp_up) + 1
        else:
            DP[r][c] = 0
            max_offset = max(r, c)

            self._rec_fixDP(grid, DP, r - 1, c, max_offset, 1)
            self._rec_fixDP(grid, DP, r, c - 1, max_offset, 1)



    def maxDistance(self, grid) -> int:
        n = len(grid)
        DP = [[-1 for i in range(n)] for m in range(n)]

        for i in range(n):
            r = i
            for c in range(i):
                self._dp_iteration(r, c, grid, DP)

            c = i
            for r in range(i + 1):
                self._dp_iteration(r, c, grid, DP)

        cur_max = -1
        for i in DP:
            cur_max = max(cur_max, max(i))

        print(DP)

        return cur_max if cur_max > 0 else -1

sol = Solution()
l = [[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,1]]
print(sol.maxDistance(l))
```

I have submitted it to leetcode.com and these are the results:

> **Runtime: 860 ms**, faster than 19.20% of Python3 online submissions for
>   As Far from Land as Possible.
>
> **Memory Usage: 14 MB**, less than 100.00%
>   of Python3 online submissions for As Far from Land as Possible.

---

Consider this simple grid

```
1    2    3
4    5    6
7    8    9
```

I am looping over the `grid` in this way: `1 4 2 5 7 8 3 6 9`. This is because when i visit `grid[r][c]` I will have already visited `grid[r - 1][c]` and `grid[r][c - 1]`.

Next, the logic is split in 2 parts: when `grid[r][c] = 0` and when `grid[r][c] = 1`.

For **grid[r][c] = 0**,

> `DP[r][c] = min(DP[r - 1][c], DP[r][c - 1]) + 1`
>
> The exception is the
>   value -1: it means it has not been found a land cell yet.

For **grid[r][c] = 1**,

> `DP[r][c] = 0`
>
> Even if this part is pretty simple (the distance between the land cell
>   and itself is 0), you also need to fix all the previous calculated
>   distances, since they could all be -1 or they could have large values.
>   This last part is executed by `_rec_fixDP`, called until the current
>   distance is lesser than the stored one.

The complexity is easy to estimate: you need to loop over all the cell at least one (one in the best case), but the `_rec_fixDP` could revisit all the previous cells. So:

Best case: `O(n^2)`

Average case: `O(n^4)`

However I suspect it is possible to do it in less than `O(n^4)`.